# How to set JPA/Hibernate flush mode application-wise?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I am looking for the method of setting the flush mode for my web application, which runs on Spring (MVC) 5.0.2.RELEASE, Hibernate 5.2.12.Final (JPA 2.1), and Spring Data 2.0.2.RELEASE.

I am able to find examples of other configurations such as `hibernate.format_sql`, etc., but cannot find one for flush mode configuration.

This is what I have now. I made a guess of how to set flush mode, but not sure whether it is right. Is it correct?

```
@Bean
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, Environment env) {

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            ...

    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.flushMode","ALWAYS");
    ...

    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what your understanding of flush mode is? JPA know FlushModeTyp AUTO and COMMIT to tell JPA if the changes in the PersistenceContext should be considered, but probably that's not what you try to achieve.

Comment: Hi Simon, I just wanted to find a way to test whether changes in flush mode solves the problem I have now in another post. Based on one answer, flush mode change may be the solution. Thanks for chimining in! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47861929/hibernate-5-x-and-spring-data-2-x-how-to-make-the-original-object-updated-in-a

Comment: cited thread is not clear, what is state of object, i.e. is attached / detached. Remember, few web app technics breaks JPA session ... suggest solve original quiestion. Here is an "XY problem"